# How to remove certain Part of JSON

Tags: php, json

Sorry for my bad English in Advance. Here is my JSON return.

https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BYzc3OGZjYWQtZGFkMy00YTNlLWE5NDYtMTRkNTNjODc2MjllXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNjExODE1MDc@._V1_UY268_CR5,0,182,268_AL_.jpg

How can I remove the part `UY268_CR5,0,182,268_AL_`. Specifically that part only. And I have many of this links. Each having different strings there. For example:

https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BYWNlMWMxOWYtZWI0Mi00ZTg0LWEwZTMtZTEzZDY0NzAxYTA4XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTQxNzMzNDI@._V1_UX182_CR0,0,182,268_AL_.jpg

As shown it is different. I want to remove the part `UX182_CR0,0,182,268_AL_`. Each of the results I have has almost the same structure but the end part I want to remove. I am on laravel and so I am encoding my jsons result from controller. Is there anyone this can be done with php?

**Update:**

Here is the code I tried.

```
$json = json_decode($data,true);

    $slice = str_replace("UY268_CR5,0,182,268_AL_","", $json);

    return $slice ['poster'];
```

The string is removed but what about different strings with different URL's like mentioned above?

Comment: Did you try a single line of code yourself?

Comment: @BeingSunny Please see the updated Question.

Comment: do you want something like this ? `https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BYWNlMWMxOWYtZWI0Mi00ZTg0LWEwZTMtZTEzZDY0NzAxYTA4XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTQxNzMzNDI@._V1_.jpg`

Comment: Yes that is exactly what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) with the combination of **lookahead** and **lookbehind**

```
<?php
$re = '/(?<=_V1_)(.+?)(?=.jpg)/';
$str = 'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BYWNlMWMxOWYtZWI0Mi00ZTg0LWEwZTMtZTEzZDY0NzAxYTA4XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTQxNzMzNDI@._V1_UX182_CR0,0,182,268_AL_.jpg';
$subst = '';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str, 1);
echo "The result of the substitution is ".$result;
```

?>

**DEMO:** https://eval.in/1044470

**REFF:** [Regex lookahead, lookbehind and atomic groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups)

**REGEX EXPLANATION:** https://regex101.com/r/aHAw5f/1

Comment: Sorry I can not vote up but this works! Accepted! one more question if you dont mind. Can you explain this? `/(?<=_V1_)(.+?)(?=.jpg)/`. I mean can you explain what those strings are?

Comment: @RESIP. glad it works for you and help you somehow. I've updated my answer with some cool and informative references. You can see the explanation of `(?<=_V1_)(.+?)(?=.jpg)` on the right side of *EXPLANATION* section on https://regex101.com/r/aHAw5f/1 site. Best of luck

Comment: Ok I figured it out. The explanation was very useful. Thanks a bunch :)